# What could be preventing me to access certain sites on the web?

Tags: windows, networking, internet-connection

Starting a few weeks ago, I realised that I am not able to access certain sites from my home internet connection (GIS sites, some universities, email providers, etc…)

Apparently these sites are not interrelated or belong to any suspicious activity. I cannot access also from my phone/tablet. I have tried with tracert, but it is not able to resolve the addresses.

I have checked the router configuration, firewall, antivirus, but nothing works. However, when I use VPN or Tor, I am able to connect with no restrictions.

What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: What happens if you ping one of the blocked sites from the command prompt? Also, did you ever install a VPN of any kind prior to these issues?

Comment: I did not install any VPN before the occurrence of the issues I mention. With ping, the host is not found.

Comment: What does "not able to resolve the addresses" with traceroute mean to you (can't access addresses or traceroute does not find an IP?) And what nameservers are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use other DNS servers than the ISP default one.
Some ISP's "censor" some webpages by removing their adress information in their DNS server lists.

You can try any "free" DNS servers like "Open DNS" or other free ones that have a policy not to censor anything.

Ti change DNS settings you can go to your controlpanel/Network/sharing find your network adapter in use. Open the properties and find "internet protocol ipv4" in the list. open it's properties and under DNS servers add two prefered DNS servers. Usually this take care of some ISP "consoring" by DNS server lists.

My windows are in "swedish" so I'm not to sure about the exact words used for the pathways in English but I'm sure you can find your network adapter and change the settings for the DNS

```
208.67.222.123
208.67.220.123
```

Are the IPv4 adresses for open DNS

Comment: Changing the options to Open DNS worked, now I can access the blocked sites, however I would like to know the reason why they got blocked, apparently by my internet provider.

Comment: My guess is that your Internet service provider don't want you to access those sites for some reason. You should put a preassure on your ISP if they censor you. As long someone is an adult there is no reason whay so ever to sencor anything. (My belief) And by putting some preassure on ISP's that sensor we might get a more free and open Internet. Itherwise soon China politics will run us all on the net.